# Index Vector and Concat Index to Element in Other Vector

Tags: r

I have a list of strings that I want to index and pass into another vector with their appropriate index from the latter vector. I have "comps", and I need to pass the elements of comps that say "Bid" into vector "bidders" with the string "Bidder" and index of appropriate element; I want to have a final list of "bidders" with element(s): "Bidder2", "Bidder4", etc. Currently I am able to get the result needed, but it is being multiplied. For example, the block of code below yields:

```
> bidders
[1] "Bidder1" "Bidder3" "Bidder4" "Bidder1" "Bidder3" "Bidder4" "Bidder1" "Bidder3"
[9] "Bidder4"
```

Notice how we get ("Bidder1", "Bidder3", and "Bidder4") x 3 because we have 3 comps who bid.

```
# which competitor bidded
comp1 <- sample(c("Bid", "No Bid"), size=1, prob=c(0.5, 0.5))
comp2 <- sample(c("Bid", "No Bid"), size=1, prob=c(0.5, 0.5))
comp3 <- sample(c("Bid", "No Bid"), size=1, prob=c(0.5, 0.5))
comp4 <- sample(c("Bid", "No Bid"), size=1, prob=c(0.5, 0.5))

comps <- c(comp1, comp2, comp3, comp4)
bidders <- c()

for (comp in comps) {
  if (comp=="Bid") {
    bidders <- append(bidders, str_c("Bidder",
                                       which(comps=="Bid")))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to use `list` instead of creating a `vector` with `c`

```
comps <- list(comp1, comp2, comp3, comp4)
```

Also, loop over the sequence

```
library(stringr)
bidders <- c()
for(i in seq_along(comps)) {
    if(comps[[i]] == "Bid") {
       bidders <- append(bidders, str_c("Bidder", i))
    }
}
```

-output

```
 bidders
[1] "Bidder1" "Bidder2" "Bidder3"
```

---

Note that `str_c` or `paste` are vectorized.  So, there is no need for a loop

```
str_c("Bidder", which(comps == "Bid"))
[1] "Bidder1" "Bidder2" "Bidder3"
```

Comment: That works! Thanks a lot!! I also tried it with comps being a vector instead of a list. They both worked. Why di you suggest suggest a list instead of a vector?

Comment: @PèreNoël in this case both works, but in general, if the number of elements in ecah of the comp vectors are more than 1, then the `c` will create a single vrector and we don't know which one is from which comp

Comment: gotcha! Thanks a lot!!